# Calculate method name for GetProcAddress

Tags: c#, marshalling

I have a C# project that needs to call into a native library and for reasons which I can't get into here, I can't use `PInvoke` so I am trying to use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`

My problem comes from the `__stdcall` calling convention. Using `__stdcall` a c++ method like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Add(int left, int right);
```

Will be exported with the name `_Add@8`, because `sizeof(int) * 2 == 8`. However, I don't want the users of my library to have to calculate beforehand how many bytes that a function will need for its parameters. (PInvoke somehow gets away with it)

Instead, I would like for my users to create a matching delegate and then give that delegate type to my library and I then I use reflection to figure out how many bytes I need to plan for. I.E.

```
public delegate int Add(int left, int right);

//My library has already loaded the dll at this point
int result = (int)MyLibrary.Call<Add>(left,right);
```

`ints` are easy enough to calculate. But how to I do this with pointers like `string` to `const char *` or `byte[]` to `unsigned char *`? Especially given that it could be on a `x64` or an `x86` system.

Luckily, `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(methodAddress, delegateType);` takes care of the actual calling for me, but I need to calculate the proper export name in order to get the methodAddress.

Comment: You are too focused on a non-existing problem.  Just provide the user with a library that does the fugly LoadLibrary + GetProcessAdresss mumbo jumbo.  Only you can ever get that right anyway.  And you know that it is `_Add@8` and always will have that name.  And if it doesn't then all hell will break lose, stack imbalance is a very ugly problem to debug.  If you insist that the user needs to get the GetProcessAddress call right then just rename the exported function with a .def file to "Add".

Comment: This library is meant to be used with any native dll that exports using __stdcall and wont know anything about the method names beforehand. The method names will be pulled from the delegates at runtime. Unfortunately, .def files wont really work as this is primarily meant to be used with thirdparty dlls.  The user will have to get the delegate correct, just like a PInvoke call, but I was hoping to infer the number after the `@` from the delegate, rather than having the user provide some sort of attribute that specifies the size of the args.